# Build-time dependancy bundling depending on env variables

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite

I have a vite application. I want to ship code under the build-time feature flag. I supply it via vite envs: `CLIENT_FEATURE_FOO`.

I don't want to ship code if the feature flag is not enabled, especially if it requires a third-party dependency.

One could write code like that:

```js
let myFn
if (import.meta.env.CLIENT_FEATURE_FOO) {
  const { someFunctionallity } = await import("new-third-party-dep")
  let myFn = function new() { /* ... */ }
} else {
  myFn = function old() { /* ... */ }
}
```

This does require top-level await. But I would've expected vite to see through the top level `await import()`, and bundle it statically.

In actuality vite doesn't see through neither build-time known branch, nor the top-level `await import()`, producing the bundle close to this (for feature disabled):

```js
let myFn
if ({}.CLIENT_FEATURE_FOO) {
  const { someFunctionallity } = await __vitePreload(() => import("new-third-party-dep"), /* ... */)
  let myFn = function new() { /* ... */ }
} else {
  myFn = function old() { /* ... */ }
}
```

The question is: how would someone accomplish such build-time feature flags such that I don't end up shipping un-usable code into the bundle with vite?